# ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

After Migration from Angular 5 to 6, I am facing an issue with Static Injector. the Error is :

> ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[StorageService -> LocalStorageService]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[StorageService -> LocalStorageService]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for LocalStorageService!
>       at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1062)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8376)
>       at _createClass (core.js:8423)
>       at _createProviderInstance (core.js:8393)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8356)
>       at _createClass (core.js:8423)
>       at *createProviderInstance (core.js:8393)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8356)
>       at NgModuleRef*.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:9064)
>       at resolveDep (core.js:9429)
>       at createClass (core.js:9309)
>       at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:9186)
>       at createViewNodes (core.js:10406)
>       at createRootView (core.js:10320)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11351)
>       at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:10838)
>       at ComponentFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:8666)
>       at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:3315)
>       at ApplicationRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.bootstrap (core.js:4550)
>       at core.js:4358
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at PlatformRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef._moduleDoBootstrap (core.js:4358)
>       at core.js:4324
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
>       at Object.onInvoke (core.js:3824)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
>       at zone.js:872
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3815)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)

```js
import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { ConfigurationModule } from './configuration/configuration.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule,
    ConfigurationModule,
    AuthModule,
    InfiniteScrollModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule
    

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my app.module file. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add the LocalStorageService under providers in your module.ts

```
providers: [LocalStorageService ]
```